# What happened with the close votes for this question?

Tags: support

The question https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3672/are-there-three-types-of-people-when-it-comes-to-making-decisions used to have several close votes. When I visited it today, they were gone, including my own.

What has happened here? Was this question closed and re-opened? Because if it was, the re-opening happened very quickly and without any discussion in favour of it, at least in the question itself.

Or was there some kind of bug here?

Comment: FWIW, I closed that question. It's a really bad question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Close votes decay after 4 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question). So this is a feature not a bug. If the question was closed and reopened, you would be able to see this in the history, which is not the case here.

If a question doesn't get enough attention to be closed by the community you can either flag for a moderator (not useful in this specific case, as the question was posed by one) or make your case on meta to give the question some attention.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the time aspect. I have no personal interest in seeing the question closed as such, other than that I think it ought to be. If the community doesn't agree, that's fine by me, I was just curious about what had happened in this particular case. Answer accepted.

Comment: +1 - Interesting. I didn't know of this expiry date thing. Cheers.

Comment: Small correction: you can and should still flag for moderator attention if you see a problem with something that a moderator has posted and can't resolve it yourself - that's why we have *multiple* moderators, so that they can act as checks on each other.

Comment: @Shog9: Give me meta-moderators or give me death! :)